# How to set a fontseries in beamer?

Tags: beamer, fonts

I'm trying to use font [lato](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/lato/) in a `beamer` presentation. Normal text should be using the light font (please, let's not discuss typography here -- I know). According to the font catalogue, I get it like so:

```
\fontseries{l}\selectfont
```

Extrapolating from how we can set "complex" font *families* (seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130886/3213)), I tried this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setbeamerfont{normal text}{series=\fontseries{l}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Test\\
  {\normalfont Test} \\
  {\fontseries{l}\selectfont Test}\\
  \textbf{Test}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But the result is not as expected:

[image]

There are no error messages.

How can I tell `beamer` to use the light font series?

I'm happy to accept solutiond for either pdflatex or lualatex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `beamer` source code says

```
\setbeamerfont{normal text}{} % ignored currently
```

So instead of trying to set the `normal font` template (which will be ignore anyway), you could set the font using `\AtBeginDocument{\fontseries{l}\selectfont}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\AtBeginDocument{\fontseries{l}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Test\\
  {\normalfont Test} \\
  {\fontseries{l}\selectfont Test}\\
  \textbf{Test}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]