# Use a different font in Beamer slide headlines

Tags: beamer, fonts, header-footer

I would like to use a serif font (Palatino) in slide text and a sans-serif one (Fira Sans) in slide headlines, but for some reason I cannot make it work.

My question is similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130878/define-a-separate-font-for-slide-titles-in-beamer), but the same approach doesn't want to work for me.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamerfont{headline}{family=\sffamily, family*={FiraSans}}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{FiraSans}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test frame title}
\framesubtitle{Test frame subtitle}
\lipsum[4]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: a screenshot of what I get]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your redefinition of `\sfdefault`. The Fira Sans family doesn't use `FiraSans` but `FiraSans-<figureoptions>` with `<figureoptions>` replaced with some letters encoding the used figures.

The following works:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{FiraSans}
\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamerfont{headline}{family=\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test frame title}
\framesubtitle{Test frame subtitle}
\lipsum[4]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! It's so easy